# Comparence of task.Status == RanToCompletion and task.IsCompleted

Tags: c#, async-await, inotifytaskcompletion

Consider this:

```
readonly INotifyTaskCompletion<Model> _modelAsync;
public INotifyTaskCompletion<Model> ModelAsync { get { return _modelAsync; } }
public ctor() // pseudo code
{
    _modelAsync = NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(GetModelAsync());
    _modelAsync.PropertyChanged += modelAsync_Ready;
}
async Task<Model> GetModelAsync()
    {
        var rv = await TaskEx.Run(new Func<Model>(() => Agent.GetModel());
        if (ModelAsync.IsSuccessfullyCompleted) Trace.WriteLine("after await completed");
        if (ModelAsync.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) Trace.WriteLine("after await not completed");
        if (ModelAsync.Result != null) Trace.WriteLine("after await result");
        if (ModelAsync.Result == null) Trace.WriteLine("after await no result");
        return rv;
 }
void modelAsync_Ready(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Result") { }// etc...
}
```

Why is it that after the await the task has not yet completed?
I always thought that the big plus of async-await pattern was: not having to write a callback any more! Async programming with the look and feel of a "normal program".

But only by subscribing to the `propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Result"));` I get notified that the Result is there.
That is approx. the same amount of work as writing a callback or backgroundworker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're awaiting the task returned from `TaskEx.Run`, but you're not setting `ModelAsync` as far as I can see.

Assuming that `ModelAsync` is `Task<Model>`, then perhaps you meant:

```
async Task<Model> GetModelAsync()
{
  ModelAsync = TaskEx.Run(...);
  await ModelAsync;
  // ModelAsync.IsCompleted is true here.
}
```

Note that `Task` and `Task<T>` do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If you're wanting to do data binding that updates when a task completes, then check out my [`NotifyTaskCompletion` type in the AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyTaskCompletion).

Comment: Updated my code fragment that uses NotifyTaskCompletion type.

Comment: The `await` is waiting for the task returned from `TaskEx.Run`. The `NotifyTaskCompletion` is waiting for the task returned from `GetModelAsync` (which is only completed when `GetModelAsync` returns).

Comment: I understand. When I use  `var task = TaskEx.Run(..); await task; <..> return task.Result;` I can give propertychanges in the `<..>` part for databinding. What is the advantage of `NotifyTaskCompletion` because a disadvantage is the extra callback?

Comment: The entire point of `NotifyTaskCompletion` is that it raises the property changed events for you. I have no idea what you're actually asking. There is no "extra callback" that I can see.

Comment: Ok I see how you look at it, and that's correct of course. My point was that I needed most of the time some extra actions on succesfull completion and subscribed to the `NotifyTaskCompletion` `PropertyChanged`. This subscription I perhaps wrongly described as a "callback". In such cases the `NotifyTaskCompletion` pattern doesn't seem to give me much extra, compared to just awaiting the task.

Comment: Right. I would definitely prefer awaiting the task in that case. I try not to use `PropertyChanged` except for data binding.